# Trying to add the_slug to my body class with no success in wordpress, can anyone advise?

Tags: php, wordpress

Using the following code to try and add the page slug as a class to my body tag but as yet having no success, could anyone advise how I might achieve this?

PHP added in functions.php

```
function add_body_class( $classes )
{
    global $post;
    if ( isset( $post ) ) {
        $classes[] = $post->post_type . '-' . $post->post_name;
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'add_body_class' );
```

Comment: What happens with your current code? Nothing returned? Incorrect information returned?

Comment: Hey, when I run the code my body tag remains empty so nothing gets added to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try adding the following to your `functions.php`:

```
function page_bodyclass() {  // add class to <body> tag
    global $wp_query;
    $page = '';
    if (is_front_page() ) {
           $page = 'home'; // If it's your Front page, apply 'home' as classs
    } elseif (is_page()) {
       $page = $wp_query->query_vars["pagename"]; // Otherwise use pagename
    }
    if ($page)
        echo 'class= "'. $page. '"';
}
```

Then change your `<body>` tag to `<body <?php page_bodyclass(); ?>>`.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the accepted answer, find the line in your header (usually `header.php`) that has:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

and change it to:

```
<body <?php body_class($post->post_type . '-' . $post->post_name); ?>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using this

```
<?php body_class(strtolower(get_the_title())); ?>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided an explanation along with your solution. Why does this solve the problem?

Comment: WordPress mainly generate slug from post or page title. So we can use post or page title in lower case as slug

Answer (score 0):

Came across this looking for way to add class that equals slug for CSS purposes.

Put this in header after `<body>`. It gets the page slug and puts it on the page in a div with id="slug".

```
<?php 
    global $post;
    $slug = $post->post_name;
    echo "<span id='slug'>" . $slug . "</div>"; 
?>
```

Put this in header before `</head>` to hide slug div (or in any CSS place).

```
<style>
    #slug {display: none;}
</style>
```

Put this in footer after `</body>`before `</html>`.  It takes the innards of the element with id="slug", finds the element with id="main" and adds a class equal to the page slug

```
<script>
var slug_class = document.getElementById("slug").innerHTML;
var main_tag = document.getElementById("main");
main_tag.classList.add(slug_class);
</script>
```